# URL Encoding yields two different results? Only one works

Tags: python, utf-8, python-requests, urlencode

I'm writing a Python script to fetch Korean vocabulary pronunciation. I have a URL ready to go, and when I open the URL in Safari, it retrieves the expected JSON from the server.

When I use `requests` to get the JSON, the call fails and no results are found.

Using Charles, I can see that the URL with my original query, a Hangul word, is URL encoded after I paste the URL into Safari and hit enter. For example, the instance of 소식 in the URL string becomes `%EC%86%8C%EC%8B%9D` on its way out.

However, when I make that same request with `requests`, the word is encoded as `%E1%84%89%E1%85%A9%E1%84%89%E1%85%B5%E1%86%A8`. Both encodings can be decoded back to the original word 소식 (using a web app to confirm). The former encoding is accepted by the server, the latter is not.

Why would I be getting a different encoding from `requests`?

Edit

Query string comes into the script as 소식

`query = sys.argv[1]
sys.stderr.write(query)` -> 소식

Interpolating the query into the URL string yields ...json/word/소식... when printing it.

Going through Charles it now looks like this `/json/word/%E1%84%89%E1%85%A9%E1%84%89%E1%85%B5%E1%86%A8/`. Everything is default, no specified encoding.

Comment: It's possible that Safari and requests use different default encodings. Did you specify an encoding when using requests? Also, are you using Python 2 or 3? Also, can you share the (relevant part of) script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are both valid url-encodings of the "same" input text:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> ulong = unquote('%E1%84%89%E1%85%A9%E1%84%89%E1%85%B5%E1%86%A8')
>>> ushort = unquote('%EC%86%8C%EC%8B%9D')
>>> ulong
'소식'
>>> ushort
'소식'
```

The strings are not actually equal, though, they have different forms in unicode:

```
>>> from unicodedata import name
>>> [name(x) for x in ulong]
['HANGUL CHOSEONG SIOS',
 'HANGUL JUNGSEONG O',
 'HANGUL CHOSEONG SIOS',
 'HANGUL JUNGSEONG I',
 'HANGUL JONGSEONG KIYEOK']
>>> [name(x) for x in ushort]
['HANGUL SYLLABLE SO', 'HANGUL SYLLABLE SIG']
```

I do not know any Korean, but it looks like the long string is composed of combining characters (you can also see similar things with latin characters and accents).  If I perform a canonical decomposition and composition of the forms, I get equality:

```
>>> from unicodedata import normalize
>>> normalize('NFC', ulong) == ushort
True
```

So, either you are using different input texts, that just happen to look the same (even `repr` is not enough to see the difference, you have to examine the codepoints) or one of the methods you are using - probably the browser - is performing a normalization/transformation.

Since the short form of the text is what worked with the server, I suggest you normalize the inputs to your script into the NFC form.

Comment: Wow, that's what's happening. I'll work on normalizing it. Thank you! You are correct in that the long is combining each character/stroke -- s-o-sh-i-k, whereas the short represents so and shik.

Comment: I finally got around to adding in the normalization and it worked flawlessly. Thank you again.